# I'm trying to speak through my discord bot, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, discord, bots

Trying to speak through my discord bot, already have some code, but it isn't working too well

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
KaburBot = Bot('.')
@KaburBot.command(pass_context = True)
async def say(ctx, *args):
    mesg = ' '.join(args)
    await KaburBot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    return await KaburBot.say(mesg)
```

KaburBot is the name of the bot and the file, and the basic idea I want to do with it is when I say something like:
.say wine
the bot replies with just the word "wine", and the original .say command is deleted.

Comment: What is the problem itself? You can't send a message at all or can't send a message without ".say" command?

Comment: @7BeholdeR7 problem I'm having is that the command just doesn't work. tried ".say wine", and the bot didn't reply, but the other commands I have for it work, so I know it's not broken.

Comment: Try changing `return await KaburBot.say(mesg)` to `await ctx.send(mesg)`. You appear to be using an older version of the library, so you might need to use `await KaburBot.send_message(ctx.channel, mesg)` instead.